# libDGX doesn't draw texture with big dimension

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, textures

I cannot draw big image in libGDX on my desktop. I have an image with dimension 9494x13082 pixels and use `batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, width, height);`. And instead of a texture libGDX draw a black square. If I compress the image to 60% or more, everything works fine. I tried to use `TextureRegion`, but that also doesn't work.
Tell me please, what could be the problem. Maybe I haven't enough RAM?

I work in Linux, OpenGL ES 2.0, 2GB Ram, minimum RAM for Java - 1GB, maximum - 2GB.

Comment: Which value do you get when you query `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` with [`glGetIntegerv `](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml)?

Comment: 3379. What is it mean?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. 8192. Can I work around this limit? Maybe, cutting image or another. TextureRegion cannot help(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: opengl texture dimension is equals h&w;
Even if you do not have a width equal to height, then the largest adjacency is also considered for another, and eventually the square is given to that memory.

Second: It is best for your picture to be no larger than 2048 * 2048. I think the maximum is 4096 * 4096.

**opengl 1 not supported POT. libgdx chang you texture to POT. so, the best texture size is power of tow.** 
with this parameter disable force POT for libgdx.

```
Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);
```

now your solution:

You have to split your photo into smaller pieces. For example 2048 * 2048(POT) then pack them with TEXTURE_PACKER. Then draw it where you need it.

Note that if you are using a compression tool, note that the compressed file is different with the graphical compression. So you do not have less memory space with jpg or png.
you should use texture compressor like : etc1, etc2, ktx , ....

i write the example code for you:

```
   // in this sample my image is 5*4 (5*4 - 2048*2048)
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
              batch.draw(texture[i,j], i*2048, j*2048, width, height);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me, how I can split image? Only outside from libGDX?

Comment: *opengl texture dimension is equals h&w* Do you have any proof for that? At least on my hardware, a 1024x2 texture does not consume the same memory as a 1024x1024 texture.

Comment: @BDL : 
It's true depending on the OpenGL ES version, OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1 have the power of two restriction. OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't have the limitation, but it restrict the wrap modes for non power of two textures.

Creating bigger textures to match POT dimensions does waste texture memory.

Comment: @Ryder95 :  you can use adobe photoshop, split tool

Comment: @Ryder95 TextureRegion has split() method.